# WX.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK click for get diffrent information from database

Tags: python, sqlite, hyperlink, listbox, wxpython

I have a problem when I do click on the listbox, In my program, I did click on the listbox will appear a video and explain about the video. I made a sample in the database are "name_link" which will appear in the listbox. expl1, expl2, expl3. Of each name_link have different information. However, that happens every time I click on one of these name_link, video that appears only Video3  and system never show the explain about video. When I click name_link video1 video2 emerging or always Video3. I am so stuck in this section.

this section during click :

```
tb4 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label='explain', pos=(20, 145))
    wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, pos=(80, 145), size=(220, 120))

self.opt = wx.ListBox(pan1, -1, pos=(10, 210), size=(480, 250), style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

def playFile(self, event):
self.player.Play()

def OnEnter(self, event):
self.opt.SetLabel(self.PatMatch()) 

def PatMatch(self):
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')    
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    for row in cur.execute("Select * From Video"):
        klmt = self.inpt.GetValue()
        if row[1] in klmt.lower():  
            self.opt.Append(row[2])         
           self.player.Load(row[4])
    return self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.playFile, self.op)
```

The data base like this :

```
id  word        name_link   explain     link
--- ------      ----------- ---------   --------

1   python      Video1      test        C:\Users\Ihsan\Downloads\Video1.MP4
2   python      Video2      test1       C:\Users\Ihsan\Downloads\Video2.MP4
3   python      Video3      test2       C:\Users\Ihsan\Downloads\Video3.MP4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. You want bind `wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK` only once. When the event is fired, you want to read out [which item (`GetSelection`)](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListBox.html) was selected when double-clicking. Use `GetSelections` for multiple selections.
2. Bad indentation: In the inner loop (`self.player…`) and with the `return self.Bind…` which should be in the innermost loop. As it is written now it will bind once to the last element. As written in point 1 this is not the way how it is done anyhow.
3. In `Bind`, `self.op` should be `self.opt`

See the [wxPython demo on the download page](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) to see how to use ListBox sensibly.

EDIT: Code sample added

```
import wx

import sqlite3

class play_model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # all the sqlite init stuff goes here, it is mocked for the sake of the example
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE video (word text, name_link text, explain text, link text)')

        newrecs = (('python', 'Video1', 'test1', r'C:\video1.MP4'),
                   ('python', 'Video2', 'test2', r'C:\video2.MP4'),
                   ('notpython', 'Video3', 'test3', r'C:\video3.MP4'),
                   ('python', 'Video4', 'test4', r'C:\video4.MP4'),
                   ('python', 'Video5', 'test5', r'C:\video5.MP4'),
                   )
        for tup in newrecs:
            c.execute('INSERT INTO video VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tup)

        self.map_explain = {}

    def get_videos(self, klmt):
        # you want to get videos matching a parameter?
        sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM video WHERE video.word = (?)'
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute(sqlstr, (klmt.lower(),))
        res = c.fetchall()

        return res

class playframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.explain = wx.StaticText(pnl, -1, 'Click in list to show explanation')
        self.klmt = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, '')
        self.srch = wx.Button(pnl, -1, u'Search…')
        self.vids = wx.ListBox(pnl, -1, style=wx.LB_MULTIPLE)

        szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        szmain.Add(wx.StaticText(pnl, -1, 'Search for video category:'), 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(self.klmt, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(self.srch, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(self.vids, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(wx.StaticText(pnl, -1, 'Explanation for video'), 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(self.explain, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        pnl.SetSizer(szmain)
        szmain.Fit(self)

class controller(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.model = play_model()
        self.search_results = []
#         print self.model.get_videos('python')
        self.frm = playframe(None, -1, 'test_playframe')
        self.frm.Show()

        self.frm.srch.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_srch)
        self.frm.vids.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.onvid_dblclick)

    def onvid_dblclick(self, evt):
        sels = evt.GetEventObject().GetSelections()
        for idx in sels:
            self.frm.explain.SetLabel(self.search_results[idx][2])
            print 'play video:', idx, self.search_results[idx]
    def on_srch(self, evt):
        klmt = self.frm.klmt.GetValue()
        # print klmt
        res = self.model.get_videos(klmt)
        if res:
            self.search_results = res
            self.frm.vids.Clear()
            self.frm.vids.AppendItems([row[1] for row in self.search_results])
        else:
            parent = self.frm
            wx.MessageDialog(parent,
                             'Not found in word category: {0}'.format(klmt),
                             'Category not found').ShowModal()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    controller(app)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I was try create some code like this. 

'def playVideo(self, evt, temp):'
        self.player.Load(evt.GetClientObject())
        self.Play(True)
        self.pjs.Clear()
        self.pjs.AppendText(evt.GetClientObject())

Its work for the video, the video can play. but for the information from column database explain, its not show. i want the information from column explain print in tb4. @nepix32

Comment: Your initial question and your answer to your question makes my brain hurt. Anyway, edited my answer to show what I would have done (tried to guess what you try to do in your program).

Answer (score 0):

I was try create some code like this.

```
def playVideo(self, evt, temp):
    self.player.Load(evt.GetClientObject())
    self.Play(True)
    self.pjs.Clear()
    self.pjs.AppendText(evt.GetClientObject())
```

Its work for the video, the video can play. but for the information from column database explain, its not show. i want the information from column explain print in tb4. @nepix32